# inserir e atualizar valores date no DB usando uma makedtextbox C#

Tags: c#, sql, data, formatação

Olá, enquanto eu desenvolvia um sistema para gerenciar os registros no DB em erro está acontecendo que ao inserir os valores os registros de data ficam vazios e ao tentar atualizar a listagem de informações ele dá um erro que diz que não consegue formatar os valores em DateTime.

```
if (status == "novo")
                {  
                    Conexao.cmdMySql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO eventos (id_event,nome_event,descricao_event,local_event,data_event,latitude_event,longitude_event) VALUES('" + codigo_tb.Text + "','" + nome_tb.Text + "','" + descricao_tb.Text + "','" + local_tb.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "','" + latitude_tb.Text + "','" + longitude_tb.Text + "')";
                    Conexao.cmdMySql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro salvo com sucesso", "Salvar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else if (status == "editar")
                {
                    DateTime data_datetime = DateTime.Now;
                    string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                    Conexao.cmdMySql.CommandText = "UPDATE eventos SET id_event='" + codigo_tb.Text + "',nome_event='" + nome_tb.Text + "',descricao_event='" + descricao_tb.Text + "',local_event='" + local_tb.Text + "',data_event='" + data_datetime.ToString(format) + "',latitude_event='" + latitude_tb.Text + "',longitude_event='" + longitude_tb.Text + "' WHERE id_event='" + event_lstv.Items[event_lstv.FocusedItem.Index].Text + "'";
                    Conexao.cmdMySql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro salvo com sucesso", "Salvar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    MessageBox.Show("Alterado com sucesso", "Alterar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
```

E essa é a mensagem de erro que acontece e a parte do código que ele tá referenciando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Conexao.reader = Conexao.cmdMySql.ExecuteReader();
            while (Conexao.reader.Read())
            { //repete até finalizar os campos

                ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(Conexao.reader[0].ToString()); //este comando é um objeto que liga sa informações do banco para o componente grafico list view organizando por índice.
                                                                                    //O índice 0 representa a coluna do ID que está oculta
                list.SubItems.Add(Conexao.reader[1].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(Conexao.reader[2].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(Conexao.reader[3].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(Conexao.reader[4].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(Conexao.reader[5].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(Conexao.reader[6].ToString());
                //Exibe os dados das colunas. Ocultando a coluna ID.

                event_lstv.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { list });
            }
            Conexao.reader.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Você está pegando o objeto do retorno do MYSQL e jogando em um DATETIME, não sei se o código que da esse erro está aí.

Comment: Porque você formata a tada?  data_datetime.ToString(format) , não bastaria usar o .Date ? data_datetime.Date;

Comment: Obrigado. Acho que o format era o erro mesmo, depois de usar o .Date ele voltou ao normal.